# Understanding multidimensional string array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am new to c++. I can not understand why the following code prints the "r" string. I think the it should be an array of 2X3X4 elements, so by pointing to the `arr[0][0][0]` i would expect the first char in the first string of the first arr=`a`, but this prints `abcd`. Can anyone explain it?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string arr [2] [3] [4]={
    {"abcd","efgh","ijkl"},
    {"mnop","qrst","xywz"}
  };

  cout<<arr [1] [0] [1] [1]<<endl;

  return 0;
}
```

**Edit:**

What makes me confused is the behavior in python. The following python code prints `a`:

```
arr=[["abcd","efgh","ijkl"],["mnop","qrst","xwyz"]]

print arr[0][0][0]
```

It addresses to the first letter of the first string in the first list.

I would think that the equivalent of this in c++ would be:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  string arr [2] [3] [4]={
    {"abcd","efgh","ijkl"},
    {"mnop","qrst","xywz"}
  };

  cout<<arr[0][0][0]<<endl;

  return 0;
}
```

by pointing to the first letter in the first string of the first array. But this prints the first string `abcd`. My question is why should i put another `[0]` in order to get to the `a`?

Comment: A `std::string` holds a string, no matter how long it is. You don't need to tell the compiler. Your array has only two dimensions.

Comment: @JonathanPotter no `std::string` involved, but your point is still correct.

Comment: @JonathanPotter This might be a stupid question, but why does the array have only 2 dimensions?

Comment: @MarcusMüller `using namspace std;` followed by `string arr...` is most definitely a `std::string`

Comment: @code0 For example, `arr[0][0]` is a `std::string` object which contains the string "abcd".

Comment: @JonathanPotter Am I understanding correctly that, in this particular instance, it is a 2dimensional array?

Comment: Examine arr using a debugger and read about multidimensional arrays.

Comment: It's a 3D array of `string`... but the bracketing of the initializer doesn't go to the full depth.  C and C++ have somewhat counter-intuitive rules for how things work when that happens, but it doesn't change the array dimensions.

Comment: @Bob__ that would be wrong, since `"abcd"` is 5 characters.

Answer (score 8):

Your initializer populates the array as follows:

```
arr[0][0][0] = "abcd";
arr[0][0][1] = "efgh";
arr[0][0][2] = "ijkl";
arr[1][0][0] = "mnop";
arr[1][0][1] = "qrst";
arr[1][0][2] = "xywz";
```

All other elements are default-initialized to empty string.

Thus, `arr[1][0][1]` is the string containing `"qrst"`, and `arr[1][0][1][1]` is the second character of that string, namely `'r'`.

Comment: I think it would help if you explained  that he only needs  2d array of string objects.

Comment: @kfsone Needs for what? The purpose of the exercise was never adequately explained. How can you know what the OP's needs are? Edit: Ah, I see. The second half of the question didn't exist at the time I posted my answer.

Comment: I think his code outlines what he was trying to do pretty well. His 3rd dimension is trying to specify the number of characters in each string, as  though he was creating a char-array, and this is backed by his initializer formatting and expectation of character location.

Comment: @kfsone Like I said - the second part didn't originally exist.

Comment: @kfsone Without the Python example, nothing suggested to me that the OP might want a 2d array; I might be unusually dense. In fact, their confusion doesn't make much sense to me in light of Python example, either (what do they think would happen in Python if the string literals were of different length?)

Answer (score 2):

You've confused the standard library `string` object with the concept of a c-string/string literal, and you've helped yourself with this by avoiding the use of the `std::` prefix. If we add this, it starts to make more sense:

```
std::string arr [2] [3] [4]={
  {"abcd","efgh","ijkl"},
  {"mnop","qrst","xywz"}
};
```

What you are declaring here is an array of 2 x 3 x 4 instances of std::string. But what you wrote looks like you *thought* you were declaring character arrays:

```
char arr [2] [3] [4] = {
  {"abcd","efgh","ijkl"},
  {"mnop","qrst","xywz"}
};
```

would almost have the effect you were trying to achieve -- in this case `arr[0][0][0]` does point to `a` rather than the string.

Unfortunately the problem here is that you've specified a final dimension of 4 and then supplied 5-character c-strings to the initializer. Remember:

```
"abcd"
```

is equivalent to

```
{ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 0 }
```

because c-strings are nul-terminated. So you would need to write

```
char arr [2] [3] [5] = {
  {"abcd","efgh","ijkl"},
  {"mnop","qrst","xywz"}
};
```

or, if what you actually want is specifically arrays of characters, not nul-terminated c-strings:

```
charr arr[2][3][4] = {
    { { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd' }, { 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h' }, ...
```

`std::string` is a discrete object, not an alias for a c-string.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string arr[2][3] = {
        { "abcd", "efgh", "ijkl" },
        { "mnop", "qrst", "wxyz" },  // who needs 'u' or 'v'?
    };

    std::cout << "arr[0][0] = " << arr[0][0] << "\n";
    std::cout << "arr[0][0][0] = " << arr[0][0][0] << "\n";

}
```

http://ideone.com/JQrDxr

Comment: The program doesn't `#include <string>`,  so it may not even be referring to `std::string`

Comment: What is the need to `#include <string>`? Your last example runs exactly the same way without `#include <string>`

Comment: @amirteymuri Portability, not every <iostream> includes <string>.

Answer (score 0):

The array you initialized is probably not what you wanted to initialize.

One dimension string array

```
string arr [2]= {"abcd","efgh"};
```

Two dimensional string array

```
string arr [2][2]= {{"abcd","efgh"}, {"ijkl","mnop"}};
```

Three dimensional string array

```
string arr [2][2][2]= {
    {
        {"abcd","qwer"},
        {"efgh","tyui"}
    }, 
    {
        {"ijkl","zxcv"},
        {"mnop","bnmo"}
    }
};
```

so, `cout<<arr [1] [0] [1] [1]<<endl;` will output 'x'

Comment: *"The array you created is not 3 dimensional"* Is too. Whatever makes you believe otherwise?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Can you explain? (I guess I don't know much about this either).

Comment: @code0 The array is very 3-dimensional. Basically [x][y][z] is x-element array of y arrays of z arrays.

Comment: @code0 There's not much to explain, really. `arr` is declared thusly: `string arr[2][3][4]`. There are three dimensions following the variable name, therefore it's a three-dimensional array. I just can't, in all honesty, apprehend the nature of the confusion.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Looking at it again, I see that I got a little confused. In the question, a three-dimensional array is declared, but only the first two are assigned values. I guess that is what confused me. It has been a while since I worked with multi-dimension arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare python to c++ because in python a list and a string is nearly the same while in c++ there completely different. In Python it doesn't matter if you write

```
arr=[["abcd","efgh","ijkl"],["mnop","qrst","xwyz"]]
```

or

```
arr=[["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l"],
    ["m", "n","o","p","q","r","s","t","x","w","y","z"]]
```

because there meaning the same. in c++ instead it treats a string as one "container" which leads to your observed behavior that it will assign these "containers" to the first indexes instead the individual chars. What you can instead do is

```
char[2][12] arr = {
                    {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l"},
                    {"m", "n","o","p","q","r","s","t","x","w","y","z"}
                   };
```

Comment: `"a"`? That's an array of 2 characters.

Comment: `char[2][12] arr`? What language is this?